# Unable to resolve host "hostname": No address associated with hostname. Подводные камни

Tags: java, android, сеть, исключения

При работе с сетью в Android (4.2.2) возникает такая ошибка, в целом ошибка понятна, не понятно дальнейшее ее поведение:
Иногда при возникновении этой ошибки запрос к серверу не завершается, а продолжается и будет выполненным в течении 2-3 минут.
Можно ли как-то это обойти, то есть: есть exception - прерываем дальнейшее использование сети?

Сейчас такая обработка ошибки, собственно только вывод в лог и закрытие соединения (за блоком try/catch):

```
try {
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    is = connection.getInputStream();
    setAvailableConnect(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    is = connection.getErrorStream();
    if (responseCode == 0) {
        appLog.error("No internet connection, error=" + e.getMessage(), true);
    } else {
        appLog.error("error #" + responseCode + ": " + getErrorFromStream(is), true);
    }
}
```

В логе сервера:

```
request #12
request #13 <-- Повторный запрос уже после exception
request #14
request #15
request #16
request #13 <-- Тот запрос на который был exception
request #17
```

В логе клиента:

```
request #12
error in request #13
request #13
request #14
request #15
request #16
request #17
```

Это рушит логику работы приложения, так как приложению важен порядок запросов и их 100% доставка (это идет синхронизация данных), поэтому запросы выполняются последовательно в одном потоке, если какой либо запрос отправлен неудачно, то он повторяется спустя некоторое время, при этом остальные запросы до этого момента не делаются.

Comment: У вас кусок вырван из контекста - какая-то ошибка, при каких-то запроса которые должны  выполняются последовательно в одном потоке, иначе прерываем дальнейшее использование сети...

Comment: Ошибка в заголовке вопроса: Unable to resolve host “hostname”: No address associated with hostname (IOException). Запрос: простой http запрос с данными. Проблема: несмотря на исключение запрос все равно доходит до сервера. Что делать? Остальные данные привел только для уточнения ситуации, возможно что-то окажется важным в решении проблемы.

Comment: И в чем проблема? Сервер не должен хранить состояние клиента, пусть клиент пошлет запрос еще раз и получит то что нужно.

Comment: В том то и дело. Клиент успешно посылает повторный запрос, проблема как раз таки в том, что спустя некоторое время до сервера доходит еще и неуспешный запрос (на который выпал exception), пример в логе сервера выше

Comment: ок, все равно не понимаю в чем проблема - ваш лог клиента: все запросы с 12 по 17 прошли успешно, синхронизация выполнена, в чем проблема? Какая собственно разница дошел потом до сервера неуспешный запрос или нет?

Comment: Пример (абстрактный): синхронизируем историю сообщений, клиент отправляет сообщения порциями по 100 штук. С точки зрения клиента отправлено 3 порции (1, 2, 3), но 2-я порция была отправлена только со второго раза. Со стороны сервера - получает порции 1, 2, 3, а потом спустя время приходит еще порция 2. В итоге на сервере 400 сообщений вместо 300. И я не могу понять почему так происходит :( Методом проб (начал отправлять timestamp в запросе) выяснил что позже приходит именно запрос, который на клиенте считается ошибочным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такие варианты:

1) нежелательный вариант - открыть долгий коннекшн и передавать все сообщения, скажем 10'000 штук. Нежелательный этот вариант потому что долгие коннекшины для мобильного девайса это проблема, особенно для мобильного интернета, и тем более если такие запросы будут регулярно.

2) посмотреть конфигурация таймаутов на сервере. Там это должно настраиваться, чтоб запросы через 2-3 минут не обрабатывались

3) Самый правильный вариант - чтоб сервер проверял - не было ли ранее таких сообщений, и если уже были то не вставлял их. В самом простом случае задать каждому сообщению порядковый номер 1,2,3 итд, или уникальный типа UUID или timestamp. (или всей пачке)

Comment: 1 - действительно, при больших данных так лучше не делать. 2 - все ок. 3 - не совсем то что я хотел, но проблему решает, спасибо.